# Having trouble adding dynamic segment to URL generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im using the ActiveRecord-reputation-system gem to add an upvote and downvote link to my chat_room app and am having some trouble getting the actual link to show up in my view.

In my Room.show I have put:

```
<%= link_to "up", vote_room_message_path(message, type: "up"), method: "post" %>
```

and I am getting an error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"vote", :controller=>"messages", :id=>"1", :room_id=>#<Message id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: nil, room_id: 1, body: nil>, :type=>"up"}, possible unmatched constraints: [:room_id]
```

What sticks out to me is "possible unmatched contrasts: [:room_id]. I have searched extensively online and the only thing I can find is that for each dynamic segment you have, you will need to pass an argument. So I pulled up my routes using rails routes and this is the route that shows for vote_room_message:

```
vote_room_message POST   /rooms/:room_id/messages/:id/vote(.:format)                                              messages#vote
```

I see two dynamic segments here (:room_id and :id) however I dont know how to claim them in my url. I have tried using

```
<%= link_to "up", vote_room_message_path(message, type: "up", [:room_id, :message), method: "post" %>
```

however this comes up with a syntax error. Any advice on how to make this work?

Comment: well, you're forgetting to end the array in the last one. `[:room_id, :message)` should be `[:room_id, :message])`

Comment: @JoshBrody apologies, I copied my code incorrectly. I tried it with the closed array and am still getting the same error

Comment: can you update your question with the error message that _syntax error_ is reporting?

Comment: `vote_room_message_path(room.id, message.id)` should ideally work, notice the `room` and `message` they are objects representing a room and message respectively and not the symbol.

Comment: or even `vote_room_message_path(room_id: room.id, id: message.id)`

Comment: Try this `<%= link_to "up", vote_room_message_path(message.room_id, message, type: "up"), method: "post" %>`

Comment: @Pavan this seemed to work for the constraint "room_id". So now the only error thats showing is for the constraint "id". How would I fix both room_id and id? I tried using (message.room_id, message.id, message, type: "up") however this doesn't work

Comment: I can't seem to find how to properly use syntax to declare my message id. Ive tried using @message. message.id. message.id. message.find(params[:id]).